# St.John of Damascus

Tags: history

I dont understand the statement of ST.John of Damascus, what he claim many of them can't be found in Quran like he say "Mary is sister of Harun and Musa" but nowhere in Quran say it,Quran say she is "daughter of Imran and people claim her to be sister of Harun", again he claim "Muhammad says this, that when the Christ had ascended into heaven God asked Him: ‘O Jesus, didst thou say: “I am the Son of God and God”?’ And Jesus, he says, answered: ‘Be merciful to me, Lord. Thou knowest that I did not say this and that I did not scorn to be thy servant. But sinful men have written that I made this statement, and they have lied about me and have fallen into error.’ And God answered and said to Him: ‘I know that thou didst not say this word.” I also don't find it like this in Quran it’s much different in Quran to check Quran 5:116-119.Again he claim "Mohammed says that the Christ asked God for a table and that it was given Him. For God, he says, said to Him: ‘I have given to thee and thine an incorruptible table" I also dont find in Quran Incorruptible table like something, it was table full of dish of heaven.Again he claim in sura bakara "He made it a law that they be circumcised and the women, too" but there is no verse like this especially the circumcision of women, where the hell he found something like that?And many more thing like she camel of god,did he himself had the faulty view of Muslim somehow by hearing hadith(or some propaganda) with Quran?I dont think Quran had changed as we have a 1st century manuscripts which contain 95% or some say 100%of Quran,if it changed christian's would have announced it to the whole world as they did with sana manuscript. So what exactly the problem?

Comment: Use paragraphing and ask one question kindly !

Comment: Do you have any title or online link on what you are reading of St. John ? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"*Mary is sister of Harun and Musa*"

19:28

> O sister of Aaron (Harun), your father was not an evil man, and your mother was not a whore.

Aaron was the name of the brother of Moses (Musa). His Sister was called Miryam (Maryam). The Quran does not mention Musa, only Aaron. The descendents of Aaron were predestinated for priesthod. "Sister of Aaron" probably means "Sister of the descendents of Aaron". It is reported in the Quran 3:35-37 that Mary (Maryam) served in the Temple, given under the care of Zekharia, who was from the tribe of Aaron (a.s.), partly parallel to weak Christian Hadith). The Quran does not mention Musa; this is an extrapolation. The father of Mary according to the Quran has the same name as the father of Musa which is the point to say that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) has confused Miryam, the sister of Aaron and Moses with Miryam, the mother of Jesus (p.b.u.h). It would be illogical to call her "Sister of Aaron" (as the Quran does) and not "Sister of Musa" because Moses (p.b.u.h) was the Prophet and he woud be the main reference.

"*O Jesus, didst thou say: “I am the Son of God and God”?’ And Jesus, he says, answered: ‘Be merciful to me, Lord. Thou knowest that I did not say this and that I did not scorn to be thy servant. But sinful men have written that I made this statement, and they have lied about me and have fallen into error.*"

This is not an exact Quran citation. As you said, the reference is probably

5:116

> And God will say, “O Jesus son of Mary, did you say to the people, `Take me and my mother as gods rather than God?'“ He will say, “Glory be to You! It is not for me to say what I have no right to. Had I said it, You would have known it. You know what is in my soul, and I do not know what is in your soul. You are the Knower of the hidden.

"*Mohammed says that the Christ asked God for a table and that it was given Him. For God, he says, said to Him: ‘I have given to thee and thine an incorruptible table" I also dont find in Quran Incorruptible table like something, it was table full of dish of heaven*"

The original is

5:111-117

> And when I inspired the disciples: «Believe in Me and in My Messenger.» They said, «We have believed, so bear witness that We have submitted.»
> And when the disciples said, «O Jesus son of Mary, is your Lord able to bring down for us a feast from heaven?» He said, «Fear God, if you are believers.»
> They said, «We wish to eat from it, so that our hearts may be reassured, and know that you have told us the truth, and be among those who witness it.»
> Jesus son of Mary said, «O God, our Lord, send down for us a table from heaven, to be a festival for us, for the first of us, and the last of us, and a sign from You; and provide for us; You are the Best of providers.»
> God said, «I will send it down to you. But whoever among you disbelieves thereafter, I will punish him with a punishment the like of which I never punish any other being.»
> And God will say, «O Jesus son of Mary, did you say to the people, Take me and my mother as gods rather than God?» He will say, «Glory be to You! It is not for me to say what I have no right to. Had I said it, You would have known it. You know what is in my soul, and I do not know what is in your soul. You are the Knower of the hidden.
> I only told them what You commanded me: that you shall worship God, my Lord and your Lord. And I was a witness over them while I was among them; but when You took me to Yourself, you became the Watcher over them—You are Witness over everything.»

"incorruptible" may be read between lines but it is not literal.

"*He made it a law that they be circumcised and the women, too*"

Simply false.

The problem is that John of Damascus is arguing *against* Islam. One can not rely on his citations.